# How to make `goapp serve` ignore changes in the .git folder?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

When running the development server for Google App Engine Go I read the following console prints:

```
INFO DATE module.py:427 [default] Detected file changes:
    .git
    .git\logs\HEAD
```

But that's just noise, how can I suppress that?

Comment: Typically you don't put your app itself in the root of your Git Repository.

Comment: @0x434D53 is spot on and should write an answer.  There are other benefits to keeping the app out of the root.